# How to make my website with multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, multiple-languages

I have difficulties on how I could translate the content in all of the pages with clicking one button.  I want to have a button on the home page and when the user choose one of the languages that this button contains, all the content in all of the pages to be in this language. For now, I know only how to do that with one page(Create buttons, when you click, you get the text translated in this language, but only at this page). And also, I do not use PHP. Thank you!

Comment: You an use Google Translate plugin or Bing Translate plugin for same purpose

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Jquery, There is a lot of ways to translate a website but they all turns around the same mechanics. You need a translator, and a language file. 
The easiest way to do so would be using the jquery plugins [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/). It's a easy to use plugins which allows you to translate your website. 
It is pretty simple, you add class `trn` to the element your want to add : 

 `<span class="trn">Text to translate</span>`

And then you add a `data` attribute to the key you want to translate to. Ex: 
`<span class="trn" data-trn-key="Hello world"></span>`

Your language files is pretty simple as well, a simple Javascript object with the first Key as your `trn-key` and then another object with the language your want to translate your key to. Ex :

```
var lang = {
    "helloworld": {
        en: "Hello World",
        fr: "Bonjour monde"
    },
    /*...*/
}
```

The plugins will replace the innerHTML of the span with the selected lang.